# Akka stream IOResult: how to check error?

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I work with Akka Streams on Scala.

Starting from 2.6.0 IOResult.status is deprecated (status is always set to Success(Done). Since 2.6.0.).

See https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/IOResult.html#status()

How to check an error?

BTW, in my tests with real error, e.g. invalid file name, status has Failure(exception) value.

Comment: According to your mentioned test case, I can guess that error details migrate to `Future` instance, so API is "flat" now.

Answer (score 5):

As Ivan mentioned, the `IOResult.status` is redundant because the mat value will return a `Failure`, as you observed.